# Best way to duplicate a ClickHouse replica?

Tags: replication, apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

I want to create another replica from an existing one by copying it.
Made a snapshot in AWS, created a new server, all my data has a copy on the new server.
Fixed the macro `replica` in config.

When I start the server it throws "No node" in error log for the first table that it finds, and gets stalled, repeating the same error once in a while.

```
<Error>: Application: Coordination::Exception: No node, path: /clickhouse/tables/0/test_pageviews/replicas/replica3/metadata: Cannot attach table `default`.`pageviews2` from metadata file . . .
```

I suspect this is because the node for this replica does not exist in Zookeeper (obviously, it was not created, because I did not run the CREATE TABLE for this replica as it is just a duplicate of another replica).

What is the correct way to do a duplication of a replica?
I mean, I would like to avoid copying the data, and make the replica pull only the data that was added from the moment in time when the snapshot was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, I would like to avoid copying the data,

It's not possible.

Comment: Ok... And in case my replica crashes and I restore it from a snapshot, will it know to pull the missing data?

Comment: No, you have to execute "create table" to create a new replica